# Angular 2+ reactive form validation - either this or that

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have a 3 field form - first name, last name, ID number - which I want to set up so that a user must EITHER enter data into the two name fields OR enter an ID number for the form to be valid and "submittable".

My code is

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.person = this.fb.group({
      'fname': [],
      'lname': [],
      'certID': []
    },{
      validator:(formgroup:FormGroup)=>{
        return this.validateInput(formgroup);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  validateInput(formgroup:FormGroup){
    if(formgroup.controls["fname"].value && formgroup.controls["lname"].value || formgroup.controls["certID"].value){
      console.log('OK');
      return {validateInputData:true};
      }
      else {
        console.log('Not OK');
      return null;
      }
  }
```

While this validation runs when the form/page is loaded and generates a 'fail'('Not OK'), the submit button is nevertheless active:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
[disabled]="submitPending || person.invalid">
Submit<span *ngIf="submitPending" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span>
</button>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your return statements backwards?

Return `null` when all is OK and the error when it is not OK.

```
if((formgroup.controls["fname"].value && formgroup.controls["lname"].value)
                || formgroup.controls["certID"].value){
  console.log('OK');
  return null;
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not OK');
    return {validateInputData: true};
  }
```

The 'validateInputData' property will be the name of the error in the errors collection.